# Using atomics with std::thread in c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, c++11, atomic

I have a thread that I want to sit in a loop until I'm ready to exit the program, at which point I want it to break out of the loop and exit so I can call `std::thread::join` on it. In the days of c++03, I would just use a bool protected by a lock in order to tell the thread when to exit. This time I thought I would take advantage of the new atomics library (specifically `std::atomic_bool`), but I'm having trouble. Below is my test case:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void setBool(atomic_bool& ab)
{
    ab = true;
}

int main()
{
    atomic_bool b;
    b = false;
    thread t(setBool, b);
    t.join();
    printf("Atomic bool value: %d\n", b.load());
    return 0;
}
```

The declaration of `thread t` spits out [this](http://pastebin.com/SpRQW4W1) monstrosity when I try to compile. The central part of the error seems to be:

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::atomic_bool&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::atomic_bool’

Why can I not get a reference to an `atomic_bool`? What should I do instead?

Comment: @NicolBolas How so? Isn't locking a variable with a mutex before accessing it a standard way to share data between threads?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to explicitly pass a ref to your thread. Using `std::ref` will create a `std::reference_wrapper` which is copyable and will carry the ref to your function.

```
thread t(setBool, std::ref(b));
```

Otherwise it will try to copy your atomic, which is uncopyable.

Comment: Why does it attempt a copy? Doesn't giving the variable name for a reference argument traditionally pass that variable by reference?

Comment: @slavik262 yes, that is true. The thread constructor does that, as you are invoking a function from which you don't know when it will execute, if you passed a reference, the reference might be invalid, thus it will copy your arguments to safely store them. If you explicitly use a ref-wrapper, it is your job to make sure that the object will outlive the thread.

Comment: Most of the time, you want to pass by value to a new thread. So that's the default.

Answer (score 8):

As bamboon explained, you have to wrap objects with `std::ref` if you really want them to be passed by reference via `std::thread`'s variable-argument constructor.  (The same applies to `std::async`.)  To avoid this counterintuitive behavior, you can use a lambda, which behaves precisely as you would expect.  Just use this to create the thread:

```
thread t([&]{ setBool(b); });
```

With lambdas, there is no need for the ref/cref nonsense when you want to pass arguments by reference.

Comment: Thanks! I'm well aware of lambdas (they're awesome) - I just wanted to minimize the amount of C++11 magic I was using for my test case to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this as well, I think you could also solve your problem by passing an address-to the atomic like so:

```
std::atomic<bool> b{false};
std::thread t(setBool, &b);
```

Where your function takes a pointer to the atomic:

```
void setBool(std::atomic<bool>* ab)
```

I'm not sure what the accepted practice is, I suppose you could pass a null pointer to the atomic this way but I'm not sure why you would want to.