# Kill an std::thread that wasn't joined

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

So I have a thread that I was running using .join() but I needed an interactive user interface while running the thread so I stopped using join because it halted the program while it ran. The ui has a stop button to kill the thread and now I need a way to stop the thread without killing the whole program because I can't use .detach(). Thanks!

Comment: Do your UI on a second thread, and join both from their parent thread, no?

Comment: You generally shouldn't be calling `join()` until either you expect the thread to have finished its work _or_ you need the thread to finish its work before you can proceed with whatever you're doing.

Comment: Also, if your thread has some sort of "while(!done)" logic, you need to tell the thread that it's done _before_ calling `join()`. Otherwise, `join()` will just keep waiting for a thread that's never going to stop.

Comment: @celticminstrel so if I had a for loop would I have to tell the program it was done with the for loop too?

Comment: Probably not. If you expect the loop to eventually end no matter what happens, you don't have to do anything extra. It's only when you're looping until some external condition changes - in my simplistic example, the assumption is that, eventually, something will set `done = true` (possibly just before joining), and then the loop will terminate.

Comment: @Ami: I don't think that helps; the UI thread still needs a way to stop the computational thread.  The relationship between the threads isn't relevant, so far as I can see.

Comment: @HarryJohnston you are right. I tried that to no avail. I was just on the plane and I tried this and it didn't work. Any ideas on how to stop a thread without just quitting the whole program? This is the only way I have gotten to work

Comment: @HarryJohnston I see what you're saying, but we just read the question differently. Given the OP's response, looks like your interpretation was right.

Answer (score 1):

There is no safe way to unilaterally terminate a thread.  Instead, the thread's code must periodically check whether the GUI thread has requested that it exit.

I'm not familiar with the new C++ library functions, but I believe you can do this with `atomic_bool`, e.g., [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103645/using-atomics-with-stdthread-in-c11).

Answer (score 0):

you could pass a reference to a bool variable to the thread and check if it is true. if it is, return from the thread.

Example:

```
bool terminate = false;
std::mutex m;

std::thread t([&terminate,&m] {

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lm{m,std::defer_lock}; //don't lock yet

    int i = 0; 
    while (true) { 

    lm.lock(); //protect terminate -> no race conditions
    if (terminate)
        return;
    lm.unlock(); //release lock for terminate

        //do what your thread should do
        std::cout << i++ << std::endl; 
    }
});

/*
do something else here
*/

m.lock();
terminate = true;
m.unlock();

t.join();
```

Comment: but because the mutex is locked by a unique_lock it will be unlocked when the unique_loc goes out of scope, what happens at the `return`

Comment: does a deferred_lock not unlock the mutex?